# Control as parameter on delegate method

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, controls

I wasn't sure on how to approach the title for this question, so I'll describe my situation hoping I'm being clear about my doubts. (If there's a better suggestion for the title, I'll change it)

For the last few days I've reading around about multithreading and GUI controls modification using that scenario.
My question concerns with passing the control to be changed as a parameter of my delegate and method.
Let's say I have a ListView1 and I want to add a group to it (it's a simple experience and has few code)

According to examples I've seen, the way to do it would be

```
Private Delegate Sub ResultsAddGroup_Delegate(ByVal FondsGroup As ListViewGroup)

Private Sub ResultsAddGroup(ByVal FondsGroup As ListViewGroup)
    If Me.ListView1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New ResultsAddGroup_Delegate(AddressOf ResultsAddGroup)
        Dim ParamArgs() As Object = New Object() {FondsGroup}
        Me.ListView1.BeginInvoke(d, ParamArgs)
    Else
        Me.ListView1.Groups.Add(FondsGroup)
    End If
End Sub
```

I usually like to pass the control as a parameter in order to keep the code clear and the methods or functions away from the specific control objects.
If I wanted to pass the ListView as a parameter for the above case, like this:

```
Private Delegate Sub ResultsAddGroup_Delegate(ByVal LView As ListView, ByVal FondsGroup As ListViewGroup)

Private Sub ResultsAddGroup(ByVal LView As ListView, ByVal FondsGroup As ListViewGroup)
    If LView.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New ResultsAddGroup_Delegate(AddressOf ResultsAddGroup)
        Dim ParamArgs() As Object = New Object() {LView, FondsGroup}
        LView.BeginInvoke(d, ParamArgs)
    Else
        LView.Groups.Add(FondsGroup)
    End If
End Sub
```

Would that represent any kind of problem for multithreading and control changing purposes?
If so, is there another way to do this without specifying the control?

On another note, is there any problem with the way I usually do my methods (as described above, with passing the control as parameter)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used the second pattern in a few projects myself.  It seems to do the job as the Ctrl.InvokeRequired is thread-safe. Using the control as a parameter is fine since it is just an an object reference.

I think in that first code-block, there is a small error in the object array initialization and this is intended:

```
Dim ParamArgs() As Object = New Object() {FondsGroup}
```

But I hesitate to change it in case I am missing something :)

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but since I'm not sure, I was hoping for the input of someone with more experience than me.
About the code, it was a copy/paste mistake, as you can see from the second block of code.
Thanks for your input.